# How to combining query's with missing results?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to develop a layout that gives a list of results layed out as per the below.

```
id    Name     Operator     Time1     Time2    Time3
```

id, Name and Operator are all from the same query

each of the others are from different query's based on the id field.

I can easily create a new query that will display as above, but I only get records where every column has a value. What I want to do is allow all records with an id name and operator to display, and if any of the time fields are not present they are simply left blank like below

```
id      Name      Operator      Time1      Time2     Time3
1       jon       abc           03:30      blank     04:50
```

I am not too experienced in Access and have no understanding of SQL, but I have reasonable understanding of VBA if that helps. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stuck.

Comment: Don't be shy.  Include the query that you have in your question.

Comment: Do you mean the individual queries? or the one that bings them all together? do you want SQL code or screen shots from access?

Comment: Try a little reading: [`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx) --
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx) -- 
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx) -- says Access 2000, but the SQL is not so different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Time1, Time2 and Time 3 are coming from three different queries or tables.If that is the case, you could try doing an outer join with the first query/table, one for each table/query:

```
SELECT
ID, Name, Operator, Time1, Time2, Time3
FROM BaseTable Q
Left join TimeTable1 ON <join condition1>
Left join TimeTable2 ON <join condition2>
Left join TimeTable3 ON <join condition3>
```

Comment: I used simplified names in my question. this is the code i have, how do i change it to respresent your solution? SELECT DayVeiwRunning.Trains.Train_ID, DayVeiwRunning.Train_Date, DPActualPlace1.Actual_Mov_Time, DPActualPlace2.Actual_Mov_Time FROM (DayVeiwRunning INNER JOIN DPActualPlace2 ON DayVeiwRunning.Trains.Train_ID = DPActualPlace2.Actual_Mov_Train) INNER JOIN DPActualPlace1 ON DayVeiwRunning.Trains.Train_ID = DPActualPlace1.Actual_Mov_Train;

Comment: A little trial and error and I have used your solution to get the results I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the query that binds the 2 query, you should use OUTER JOINS

Comment: ok this is the sql access generated do I replace the INNER with OUTER?. SELECT DayVeiwRunning.Trains.Train_ID, DayVeiwRunning.Train_Date, DPActualPlace1.Actual_Mov_Time, DPActualPlace2.Actual_Mov_Time
FROM (DayVeiwRunning INNER JOIN DPActualPlace2 ON DayVeiwRunning.Trains.Train_ID = DPActualPlace2.Actual_Mov_Train) INNER JOIN DPActualPlace1 ON DayVeiwRunning.Trains.Train_ID = DPActualPlace1.Actual_Mov_Train;